# Notepad++ auto "

Tags: html, notepad++

when writing with notepad++ it adds a " if you are doing an element and are naming a element

I was wondering if I could have it only add the " after I hit the spacebar or if this is possible.

for example

```
<input type=" <-- it would automatically add another ", but I would only want it after I name the variable like
<input type="text <--- then add the " after I hit spacebar, is this already made or should I try to program it.
```

Thanks for your knowledge.

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't add `"` for me. Are you using an extension?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing addons for it but what happens is for example you are writing printf( , now you will add " . Notepad++ makes sure that closing " is added automatically.

Comment: Yea, I just don't like that I have to arrow over after it is done though, usually I am just making variables with the " marks